# Best cover for water main

Tags: basement

What's the easiest and best solution to cover my main water shut-off valve in the basement?

Cut drywall to the dimensions and put a handle on it, or a plastic cover with the right dimensions, or is there another option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution - hang a picture over it - perhaps something with a water theme.

Arguably "best" solution - use an access panel, it's what they are made for.
 [image]

Comment: My only concern is how small the opening is. Doubt ill find an access panel that small, may have to cut. Well see. The opening is too low on the wall for a picture for sure. My daughter will throw it off in a hearbeat.

Comment: You did not provide dimensions, and cutting a larger hole is of little matter anyway - I find 4x6 and 6x6 inch panels easily. If the picture was about twice as wide as needed it could have two screws into the stud (top and bottom, through the frame) to hold it, and not be easily thrown off.